# Check if folder exists in Powershell, open if it does

Tags: powershell, directory

Im trying to make a script that opens a specific folder based an order number I type in. They are in subfolders that narrows it down, so C:\2xx\220\220947-something_irrelevant, etc. I made it to the 220 folder, but in the next one some of the folders are merged, so there might be a 220944-949-something_irrelevant. What I'm thinking is making a loop that searches for a folder containing the order number, and opens it if it finds it, and if not, if tries one number lower, maybe 10-20 times, but I'm not sure how to search for folders containing a subfolder with a name that consists of a string, or even open a folder without the full name.

```
### Promt for Project Number
$Pnum= Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Project Number"

#### Create path
$Path= "C:\" +$Pnum.Substring(0,1) +"xx\" +$Pnum.Substring(0,3)

### Open the folder 
ii -Path $Path

### This is where I'm lost <-----
$Fullpath = $Path + $Pnum +"*.*"
$Fullpath
#Get-ChildItem -Include $Fullpath -Name
explorer $Fullpath +"*.*
```

Comment: Can you provide a better example of an actual project number being entered and the actual full path it should find?

Comment: Really missing enough context to give a good answer, but the `-Recurse` and/or `-Depth` parameters for `Get-ChildItem` should help you get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always step thru your code one step at a time to make sure you are getting what you'd express before moving to the next.

This allows for better coding habits, easier debugging, and a more explicit understanding that your code path is being traversed as expected.

```
$RootPath = 'D:\Temp\2xx\220\'
'220947-something_irrelevant','220944-949-something_irrelevant' | 
ForEach-Object {
    New-Item -Path $RootPath -Name $PSItem -ItemType Directory -WhatIf
}
# Results
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\2xx\220\220947-something_irrelevant".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Temp\2xx\220\220944-949-something_irrelevant".
#>

$RootPath = 'D:\Temp\2xx\220\'
'220947-something_irrelevant','220944-949-something_irrelevant' | 
ForEach-Object {
    New-Item -Path $RootPath -Name $PSItem -ItemType Directory -Force
}
# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\Temp\2xx\220


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                
d-----         12-Aug-22     11:30                220947-something_irrelevant                                                         
d-----         12-Aug-22     11:30                220944-949-something_irrelevant 
#>


Clear-Host
$RootPath = 'D:\Temp\'
((Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath -Directory -Recurse) -match '\b^\d{3,7}\b').FullName
# Results
<#
D:\Temp\2xx\220
D:\Temp\2xx\220\220944-949-something_irrelevant
D:\Temp\2xx\220\220947-something_irrelevant
#>

Clear-Host
$RootPath = 'D:\Temp\'
((Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath -Directory -Recurse) -match '\b^\d{3,7}\b').FullName -match (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a Project Number')
# Results
<#
Enter a Project Number: 220944
D:\Temp\2xx\220\220944-949-something_irrelevant


Enter a Project Number: 220947
D:\Temp\2xx\220\220947-something_irrelevant
#>


Clear-Host
$RootPath = 'D:\Temp\'
Invoke-Item -Path $(((Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath -Directory -Recurse) -match '\b^\d{3,7}\b').FullName -match (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a Project Number'))
```

You could have also just done this:

```
Clear-Host
((Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\' -Directory -Recurse) -match (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a Project Number')).FullName
# Results
<#
Enter a Project Number: 220944
D:\Temp\2xx\220\220944-949-something_irrelevant


Enter a Project Number: 220947
D:\Temp\2xx\220\220947-something_irrelevant
#>
```

Honestly, I'd do this, and eliminate the whole, hey user, type something thing.
Just use a simple select and process. You can also scroll or filter in Out-Gridview, then select to process

```
Clear-Host
((Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\' -Directory -Recurse) -match '\b^\d{3,7}\b').FullName | 
Out-GridView -Title 'Select a project number' -PassThru | 
Invoke-Item
```